# mysql - IF...ELSE or CASE in ORDER BY statement

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo, sql-order-by

In my query below I am not getting the desired result. I want the results to sort according to the latest event occurrence based on two different date fields of two different tables. Let's see the query first.

```
SELECT R1.swp_to, R1.swp_type, R1.swp_date, M.mem_fname, M.mem_lname, M.mem_last_activity, DP.dp_photo, GREATEST(R1.swp_date, R2.swp_date) FROM swipes AS R1
LEFT JOIN swipes AS R2 ON(R1.swp_to = R2.swp_by AND R2.swp_to = R1.swp_by AND R2.swp_type <> 'left')
LEFT JOIN members AS M ON(R1.swp_to = M.mem_id)
LEFT JOIN display_photos AS DP ON(R1.swp_to = DP.dp_mem AND DP.dp_index = 1)
LEFT JOIN messages as MSG ON ((R1.swp_to = MSG.msg_from OR R1.swp_to = MSG.msg_to) AND (R1.swp_by = MSG.msg_from OR R1.swp_by = MSG.msg_to))
WHERE R1.swp_by = :mem AND R2.swp_by IS NOT NULL AND R1.swp_type <> 'left'
ORDER BY IF(MSG.msg_time IS NULL, 0, 1), R1.swp_date
```

Here in the `ORDER BY` statement we can see that there are two TIME fields `msg_time` and `swp_date`. Whenever there is a new match `swp_date` updates and when there is a new message `msg_time` updates. The records fetched using this query must be sorted as per the latest event occurrence (whichever date is the earliest of the two). My current `ORDER BY` statements does not fulfill the requirement. What am I missing here?

Comment: `LEFT JOIN swipes AS R2` is INNER JOIN due to `WHERE ... R2.swp_by IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: @Akina how is that helping here?

Comment: *... as per the latest event occurrence...* and then *...whichever date is the earliest of the two...* This needs clarification.

Comment: Nothing can help - you want "sorted as per the latest event occurrence" which needs grouping (explicit or implicit as window function or subquery) - but it is absent. *how is that helping here?* Just because a bug doesn't solve the problem doesn't mean it shouldn't be fixed.

Comment: @forpas I don't know how to make it more clear. Say I got a new match at 6:30pm (recorded at `swp_date`) then I received a new message at 6:31pm (recorded at `msg_time`) then the record of 6:31pm should be on top. After that, say if I again received a new match at 6:35pm, then now this is the newest record and it should come at the top followed by the previous record of 6:31pm. The sorting here is based on two different date fields whichever gives the earliest record. I can't simplify it more than this. Hope this helps :)

Comment: @Akina INNER JOIN or LEFT JOIN both are giving the same results. How is having LEFT JOIN here a bug? Would like to learn :)

Comment: You are describing sorting by the *latest* which I understand is **the most recent** date but you use the term *earliest*, this is why I asked for clarification but still you use *earliest*. Anyway you are also checking for nulls so there is a case a date to be null, right? In which case the sorting should be based on the other.

Comment: @forpas date won't be null and yes as you said "the most recent" date. Please help :)

Comment: @forpas here `msg_time` comes from `messages` table where there is a possibility that no messages were sent or received among the users hence making the record 0. Since, the record is 0 therefore, yes `msg_time` can be taken as NULL. Sorry, I missed out in the earlier comment. However, `swp_date` will always be there.

Comment: See my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function [`GREATEST()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest):

```
ORDER BY GREATEST(COALESCE(MSG.msg_time, R1.swp_date), R1.swp_date) DESC
```

Comment: This code is obvious that sorts the results by the greatest date of the 2 dates. If this is not what you want you must edit your question and explain.

Comment: I have a new match 6 minutes ago and its on top while a message received 3 minutes ago at the bottom. The message should go on top automatically as it's the earliest received.

Comment: And what are the values of both columns for the 2 messages?

Comment: Even I understand that it should work by sorting the greatest one between the two but its not working/sorting.

Comment: So maybe there is a problem with your data? What is the data type of these columns?

Comment: Values: for `msg_time` its `2020-04-15 01:13:00` and for `swp_date` its `2020-04-15 01:10:32`

Comment: Datatypes are `timestamp` for both.

Comment: The function greatest() works as expected for timestamps as you can see here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2t3K5xeNPUnv3P78KfP9e8/0 so I can't say what the problem is.

Comment: I see it's working for two timestamp fields of same table. What about from two different tables as in my problem?

Comment: They are 2 timestamps in the same query and they are compared. There is no difference for the result.

Comment: But you did not use GREATEST in the ORDER BY clause. Even, I have already used GREATEST in the SELECT statement 1st line as you can see which is working but same is not working in the ORDER BY clause.

Comment: Ok I missed DESC at the end. Tell me if this was the problem.

Comment: Oh yes! Worked.. Now it's working as desired. After all the difficulty, I got it up. Thanks a lot man.. You stayed with me all through. I really appreciate it. :D

Comment: Thank you.. Without your help, I would have been stuck there still. I appreciate your efforts, really. Thanks again :)